# How to have a sidebar on the right in a responsive page with maximum width?

Tags: css, layout, responsive-design, css-float

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve with my page:

[image: Desired layout]

Basically, the hero and sidebar are two columns on the page. The hero text and image should both be in one `div`, so they should be treated as one element, like the sidebar. The `div` with the `content` ID has `max-width: 1150px;`. The reason I'm including the hero text and image separately is because I want to point out that the hero image is a `div` with a `background-image`, as opposed to an `img` element.

The elements are structured like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="hero">
        <div id="heroText">
        </div>
        <div id="heroImage">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
    </div>
</div>
```

The method I'm using right now is where I put `float: left;` on the `div` with ID `hero`, and `float: right;` on the `div` with ID `sidebar`.

When I do this, and resize my browser below 1200px (margins + hero `max-width` + sidebar `width`), the sidebar goes below the hero, instead of the hero shrinking below its `max-width` value `800px`.

How can I make the hero start to shrink instead of what happens now, the hero holding up until the browser shrinks below 900px (margins + hero `width`).

The CSS used currently is below:

```
#content
{
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
#hero
{
    float: left;
    max-width: 800px;
    width: 100%;
}
#heroText
{
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: lighter;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
#heroText p
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
#heroImage
{
    background-image: url(heroImage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 450px;
    text-align: center;
}
#heroButton
{
    margin-top: 90px;
    width: 240px;
}
#news
{
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
}
#newsPane
{
    background-color: #666666;
    border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #fff;
    height: 450px;
    width: 300px;
}
#newsPaneText
{
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: lighter;
    max-height: 350px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
#newsPaneText h1
{
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#newsPaneText small
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#newsPaneButton
{
    margin-left: 60px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 180px;
}
#emailPane
{
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 130px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#emailForm
{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
#emailField
{
    background-color: #fff;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 14pt;
    height: 27px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 280px;
}
#emailSubmitButton
{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 120px;
}
#emailFormStatus
{
    float: left;
    font-size: 11pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: could you post your CSS code too please

Comment: Okay, I posted it. Anyway, the `#news` is the sidebar, and `#newsPane` and `#emailPane` are smaller parts of the sidebar, but don't worry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/sMmEV/)**

*HTML:*

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="news">
    </div>
    <div id="hero">
        <div id="heroText">
        </div>
        <div id="heroImage">
        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

*CSS:*

```
#content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 1150px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
#hero {
    max-width:800px;
    margin-right:300px;
}
#heroText {
    font-family: Lato;
    font-size: 24pt;
    font-weight: lighter;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    background:#FF6699;
}
#heroImage {
    background-image: url(heroImage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 450px;
    text-align: center;
    background:#6699FF;
}
#news {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height:600px;
    background:#66CC33;
}
```

Comment: Question, how can I make it work without having `<div id="news">` first? I need to use media queries when the screen is too narrow, to collapse the sidebar and have it go under the `<div id="hero">`.

Comment: @PhoenixLogan like this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/sMmEV/3/ remove `position:absolute;` on news with your media query so it collapse under  hero.

Comment: This is much simpler than using `float` actually... I didn't know `position: absolute` applied to the parent element, thought it was for the whole page. Good to know.

Comment: yes, but you musn't forget to use position relative on parent (in your canse #content) if you want the element to position relative to it.

Comment: I wondered why that `position: relative;` was in `#content`. And I was going to remove it...